# How to make scroll for inner block?

Tags: html, css

I have a children block `.body` I need to make vertiacal scroll if contant is not fit to the parent `#container`. Just scroll content inside `.body` and dont scroll `.header`.

```css
#container {
  min-height: fit-content;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: inherit;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My full [code is](https://jsfiddle.net/3xt829bn/3/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make `.body` scrollable, you have to assign it a definite height.

That, in turn, means that you have to assign `#container` with a definite height:

```css
#container {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: inherit;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you change only  height: 50vh;? What if I need parent container with 80% of full height?

Comment: Full height of what? :) I assumed you're going for 50% of the window's height - so if you want 80% just use `80vh`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```css
#container {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**,

Just give specified height to the conatiner not `fit-content`

Like This

```
#container {
  min-height: fit-content;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
```

See The Snippet below

```css
#container {
  min-height: fit-content;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 200px;
  
}

.body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: inherit;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
  Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
      <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
            <div class="item">
      Item
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```